# Should gradle 2.4.4 read ~/.gradle/init.gradle automatically

Tags: gradle

I am finding that gradle 2.4.4 does not read `~/.gradle/init.gradle` unless I explicitly pass `--init-script`. Is this the expected behavior?

`gradleUserHomeDir` is `/home/bigtop/bigtop/~/.gradle`, which is very strange. 
`System.getProperty("user.home")` is `/home/bigtop`, so I do not know where that strange pathname is coming from yet.

- solution: someone had set GRADLE_USER_HOME to a silly value.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/userguide/init_scripts.html#N170CC

Comment: Any advice given that it does not read automatically for me?

Comment: Please check the path of the Gradle user home directory. Simply add `println gradle.gradleUserHomeDir` to your `build.gradle` or `settings.gradle` file and check the output, when you run Gradle.